# dlerror: Undefined symbol "_nss_cache_cycle_prevention_function" on FreeBSD 7.2

Tags: c, freebsd, linker-warning

I have an ANSI C program that dynamically loads a .so file using dlopen() passing RTLD_LAZY. I receive

```
Undefined symbol "_nss_cache_cycle_prevention_function"
```

warnings whenever the .so file is accessed in FreeBSD 7.2. nss_cache_cycle_prevention_function() is not one of my program's functions and I imagine must be coming from FreeBSD. This might also be a problem on Linux too although I am not experiencing the issue there. I would prefer not to load FreeBSD specific header files into my program. I would like to either include this function in a portable way or suppress these warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean saying "I receive warning"?  Does your program
examine the value returned by `dlerror()` and prints it if it is not NULL?

The `_nss_cache_cycle_prevention_function` is a marker symbol which is used by `nsdispatch(3)` on FreeBSD to determine whether to employ the services of `nscd(8)`, the name service caching daemon.  It is perfectly normal that it does not exist in an
executable or a shared library.

But when `nsdispatch(3)` executes `dlsym(3)`, and the symbol is not found, the error will be set.  And `dlerror(3)` returns the description of the *last* error, and not the description of the error of the last *call*.  I suspect that's what you are hitting.

The solution (quite portable) would be to:

- for `dlopen(3)`, check its return value before using `dlerror()` to see whether there was an error at all;
- for `dlsym(3)`, since `NULL` is a valid return value,
  to call `dlerror()` in a void context *before* the call to `dlsym(3)`;  that will clear any previous error, so that whatever the second call to `dlerror(3)` returns later on can be trusted.

In general, it will not harm anything to call an empty `dlerror()` before any other dl* calls.

Comment: Yes, my program spits out any non NULL dlerror() return values to a log after calling dlsym(). I did what you said and called dlerror() before I called dlsym() and the Undefined symbol warnings are gone! Thanks.